# property not found on object UiTableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c

i'm trying to show fetch data from core data into my tableview the problem is i get the.

´Property yttitle not found on object of type UITableView´

i've made sure the cell identifier is correct and the yttitle and the other are synthesized correctly. Why am i getting this error?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil) cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    // Configure the cell...

    NSManagedObject *device = [devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.ytTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device valueForKey: @"songName"]];
    cell.ytAuthor.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device valueForKey: @"author"]];


    [cell.ytThumbnail.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
    [cell.ytThumbnail.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];

    NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device valueForKey: @"link"]]]];
    UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];


    cell.ytThumbnail.image = image;




return cell;
}
```

Comment: Because the cell is declared to be of type `UITableViewCell`. The compiler doesn't know jack about run-time types.

Comment: You are using a `UITableViewCell`. You need to use the correct class for the `UITableViewCell` subclass that you have created with the property `ytTitle`.

Comment: You should replace UITableViewCell *cell with YourCustomCell *cell (The subclass of  UITableViewCell where you synthesized the property yttitle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably If I understand what you want to do, creating a custom cell is not necessary. You can simply use the *UITableViewCell* with *UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle* and use the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil) cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    // Configure the cell...

    NSManagedObject *device = [devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device valueForKey: @"songName"]];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device valueForKey: @"author"]];

    [cell.imageView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
    [cell.imageView.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];

    NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device valueForKey: @"link"]]]];
    UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];


    cell.imageView.image = image;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This seem to work but it gives me another error. "interface builder storyboard compilation Failed". is this something u have any experience with?

Comment: How did you configure the cell in the storyboard? With this code you only need to set the style to *subtitle* and the identifier to *Cell*

Answer (score 3):

UITableViewCell doesn't have that properties, you have to create your own custom cell view and load it, you can use this code to load it from an xib

```
NSArray *xibObj = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTVCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    for(id currentObj in xibObj){
        if ([currentObj isKindOfClass:[CustomTVCell class]]) {
            cell = (CustomTVCell *) currentObj;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's complaining because you try to call this property (yttitle) on UITableViewCell object and there isn't any property like that. You should cast UITableViewCell to your custom class like that:

```
YOURCUSTOMTableViewCell *cell = (YOURCUSTOMTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
if (cell == nil) cell = [[YOURCUSTOMTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

And make sure your YOURCUSTOMTableViewCell contain the property (yttitle, etc).
Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using custom cell for this TableView? Note that your method is return and using standard `UITableViewCell`, and this standard cell don't have a `@propoerties` like `ytTitle` and `ytAuthor`.

So if you're using custom cell you have to change it in three places in your code:

```
- (MyCustomCellClass *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCustomCellClass *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil) cell = [[MyCustomCellClass alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
...
```

If you declare properties in your view controller (this don't make sense) you should move it to custom cell and get rid of it in VC.